# Como puedo hacer un informe de Relación de compras por empresa y por proveedor con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
$grupo_empresas = [
    ['id_empresa' => 1, 'id_proveedor' => 101, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 101', 'compra' => 40],
    ['id_empresa' => 1, 'id_proveedor' => 102, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 10],
    ['id_empresa' => 2, 'id_proveedor' => 101, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 20],
    ['id_empresa' => 2, 'id_proveedor' => 102, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 30],
    ['id_empresa' => 3, 'id_proveedor' => 103, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 103', 'compra' => 50]
];
```

Recorriéndolo con un foreach obtengo:

```
<?php foreach ($grupo_empresas as $cia) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $cia['id_empresa'] ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $cia['id_proveedor'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cia['proveedor'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cia['compra'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sera posible obtener el siguiente informe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿O por el tipo de array que tengo no será posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien, el `foreach()` es un buen comienzo. Continúa con este código:

```
<?php

$grupo_empresas = [
    ['id_empresa' => 1, 'id_proveedor' => 101, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 101', 'compra' => 40],
    ['id_empresa' => 1, 'id_proveedor' => 102, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 10],
    ['id_empresa' => 2, 'id_proveedor' => 101, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 20],
    ['id_empresa' => 2, 'id_proveedor' => 102, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 102', 'compra' => 30],
    ['id_empresa' => 3, 'id_proveedor' => 103, 'proveedor' => 'Proveedor 103', 'compra' => 50]
];

// inicializo los elementos del array que buscas
foreach($grupo_empresas as $g)
    $r[$g['id_proveedor']][$g['id_empresa']]=0;
// acumulo las compras
foreach($grupo_empresas as $g)
    $r[$g['id_proveedor']][$g['id_empresa']]+=$g['compra'];
// busco el máximo de id_empresa
$m=0;
foreach($grupo_empresas as $g)
    if($m<=$g['id_empresa']) $m=$g['id_empresa'];
// trazo la tabla
$txt = '<table border>';
foreach($r as $j=>$proveedor){
    // cabecera
    if($j==101){
        $txt.='<tr>'
            .'<td>Proveedor</td>';
        for($i=1;$i<=$m;$i++)
            $txt.='<td>Empresa '.$i.'</td>';
        $txt.='<td>Total</td>'
            .'</tr>';
    }
    // contenido
    $txt.='<tr>'
        .'<td>Proveedor '.$j.'</td>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$m;$i++){
        if(!isset($proveedor[$i]))
            $proveedor[$i]='-';
        $txt.='<td>'.$proveedor[$i].'</td>';
    }
    $txt.='<td>'.array_sum($proveedor).'</td>'
        .'</tr>';
}
$txt.='</table>';

echo $txt;
```

En cualquier caso, salvo para casos muy puntuales, no te tortures con los arrays y recurre a las bases de datos, que te permiten llegar a estos mismos resultados con simples consultas.